# How to return start of linked list from function C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have a function `readPatientDataFromFile` that reads data from a file and stores it in a struct. The function should return a pointer that points to the start of a linked list but instead the pointer that is returned points to the end of the list.

Here is the complete implementation of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct patient
 {
    char firstname[30];
    char lastname[30];
    int age;
    struct appointment *appointment_details;
    struct patient *next;
    
};

struct patient * readPatientsFromFile(char *filename);
struct patient * appendPatient(struct patient *endPtr, struct patient *newPatient);


int main(){
    struct patient *patientPtr;
    int i = 1;

    char patients_filename[] = "patients.txt";

    patientPtr = readPatientsFromFile(patients_filename);    
    printf("---------------------------\n");
    while(patientPtr != NULL){
        printf("Patient ID: %d\n", i);
        printf("Name: %s %s\n", patientPtr->lastname, patientPtr->firstname);
        printf("Age: %d\n", patientPtr->age);
        printf("----------------------------\n");
        patientPtr = patientPtr->next;
        i++;
    }
}

struct patient * appendPatient(struct patient *endPtr, struct patient *newPatient){
    endPtr->next = newPatient;
    return (endPtr->next); 
}

struct patient * readPatientsFromFile(char *filename){
    FILE *ifile;
    ifile = fopen(filename, "r");
    struct patient *startPtr = NULL;
    struct patient *endOfPatients = NULL;
    size_t c;
    if (ifile != NULL){
        struct patient *patientPtr = (struct patient *) malloc(sizeof(struct patient));
        do {
            c = fread(patientPtr, sizeof(struct patient), 1, ifile);
            // create linked list
            if (startPtr == NULL){
                startPtr = patientPtr;
                endOfPatients = startPtr;
            }
            else {
                endOfPatients = appendPatient(endOfPatients, patientPtr);
            }
            printf("First Name: %s\n", startPtr->firstname);
        }
        while(c >= 1);
        endOfPatients->next = NULL;
        fclose(ifile);
        printf("Reading data from file successful!!!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Error reading from file");
    }
    return startPtr;
}
```

As I understand it, the `printf` statement in the `readPatientsFromFile` function should always output the same thing but from the output (attached) below, it seems that the pointer that should point to the start of the list keeps getting updated for each iteration of the loop.
Here's the output of the code:

```
First Name: John
First Name: Jane
First Name: Lloyd
First Name: Jane
First Name: Jane
First Name: John
First Name: Jane
First Name: Lloyd
First Name: Paulo
First Name: Paulo
Reading data from file successful!!!
---------------------------
Patient ID: 1
Name: Coelho Paulo
Age: 49
----------------------------
```

I'd like to know why the code is not running as expected. Thanks.

Comment: recommend a typedef for your struct: `typedef struct patient patient;` for better viewing purposes

Comment: It doesn't look like you are `malloc`ing a new node each loop. If you are just assigning the data to the same node each time, the first and last are the same.

Comment: @EdmCoff Thanks so much. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EdmCoff, the problem was that I didn't allocate memory for new nodes in the list with `malloc` so the data was being assigned to the node each time. The solution was to move the `malloc` statement into the while loop.
The corrected `readPatientsFromFile` is given below:

```
struct patient * readPatientsFromFile(char *filename){
    FILE *ifile;
    ifile = fopen(filename, "r");
    struct patient *startPtr = NULL;
    struct patient *endOfPatients = NULL;
    size_t c;
    struct patient *patientPtr

    if (ifile != NULL){
        
        do {
            patientPtr = (struct patient *) malloc(sizeof(struct patient)); // corrected portion
            c = fread(patientPtr, sizeof(struct patient), 1, ifile);
            // create linked list
            if (startPtr == NULL){
                startPtr = patientPtr;
                endOfPatients = startPtr;
            }
            else {
                endOfPatients = appendPatient(endOfPatients, patientPtr);
            }
            printf("First Name: %s\n", startPtr->firstname);
        }
        while(c >= 1);
        endOfPatients->next = NULL;
        fclose(ifile);
        printf("Reading data from file successful!!!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Error reading from file");
    }
    return startPtr;
}
```